# Quick Question: Variance of a two related Gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance

I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. Both follow a Gaussian distribution, and $$X \sim N(0,1)\;.$$

After some manipulation, I got that $$P(X \leq z) = P(kY \leq z)$$

where $k$ is some constant.

Would this imply that $X=kY$, and therefore $\operatorname{Var}(kY)=k^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)=k^2$?

Comment: You didn't give the parameters of $Y$, only the distribution, so I don't know the value of $Var(Y)$

Comment: Who's "c", when in your question, you were talking about "k", before?

Comment: My apologies, the "c" was supposed to be a "k". I'm make the correction.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the parameters of Y. But, would it instead be correct to reason that $$X= kY$$ and therefore  $$Var(X)=Var(kY) \to 1=k^2*Var(Y) \to Var(Y) = \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: $P(X \leq z) = P(kY \leq z)$ for every $z$ only says $X$ and $kY$ have the same distribution, so the equality $X=kY$ is in *distribution*.

Comment: Would that then imply that Var(Y) cannot be derived in the above fashion? If X and kY have the same distribution, would that suggest that the respective variances are related in some way?

Comment: If they have the same distribution they naturally have the same variance (use @ while replying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $kY = X$ and $\mathsf{Var}(X) = 1$, then it must be true that $$\mathsf{Var}(kY) = 1 $$ and thus $$k^2\mathsf{Var}(Y) = 1$$ and thus $$\mathsf{Var}(Y) = \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: But would $$P(X \leq z) = P(kY\leq z)$$ give the implication that $$X=kY$$

Comment: @EfficientRation If that equality holds for all $z$, then yes.

Comment: That would make sense. Thank you!